# Linux Azure App Service - Unable to populate AppServiceAppLogs in Log Analytics

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics, ilogger

I am struggling to populate the Log Analytics `AppServiceAppLogs` sink with application logging. I have a .NET Core Web Api hosted in a Linux hosted App Service Plan and using the default MS `ILogger` According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs), `AppServiceAppLogs` is supported on .NET Core on Linux, but I simply can't get the additional category in Log Analytics.
Here is my existing configuration:

###### Log Analytics

[image: Log Analytics]

###### appsettings.json

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

###### Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
});
```

###### Controller

[image]

###### File System Logs

[image: File System Logs]

Comment: try setting stdoutLogEnabled to true, could you please check the log stream logs to see if the logs are coming there or not.

Comment: @Cam Bruce, Are you trying for only AppserviceApplogs or also appserviceconsolelogs?

Comment: @pavan `AppserviceApplogs`. AppServiceConsoleLogs are working as expected

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I see the app logs coming through  the log stream/console, but no log files on the filesystem or in `AppServiceAppLogs`

Comment: What is the version of your App?

Comment: @Harshitha it's a .NET 8 Web API

Comment: can you find any logs when you access this url: https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker/zip . also try this way to generate the logs https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-app-service-logging-how-to-monitor-your-web-apps-in-real/ba-p/3800390

Comment: yes, I have `_default_docker.log` `_docker.log` `_easyauth_docker.log` `_msi_docker.log`

Comment: @CamBruce - As per this [blog](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/11/01/App-Service-Integration-with-Azure-Monitor.html#:~:text=The%20table%20below%20shows%20the%20current%20availability%20for%20the%20log%20categories.) AppServiceAppLogs is not supported in Linux Environment for .NET Core

Comment: @Harshitha in this [MS Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) (which is newer) it says that .NET Core is supported

Comment: Even I tried from my end..unable to see the logs.Once try with .Net 7 version..may be that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Console logs are basically populated from the STDOUT and STDERR and they are mapped to Informational and Error categories.

To send messages to the AppLogs, you can try the following:

"x-ms-applog:informational:base64:base64String"
"x-ms-applog:warning:base64:base64String"
"x-ms-applog:error:base64:base64String"
"x-ms-applog:critical:base64:base64String"

Benefits:

1. Multi-line logs (useful for callstacks)
2. Verbosity levels
3. Independent channel from middlewares.

It works for:

1. It works for any Linux on App Service offering or custom container image on Linux on App Service using any stack that can write to the stdout (basically every stack can do this).
2. It works for any custom container image in Windows Containers on App Service using any stack that can write to the stdout (basically every stack can do this).
3. It works for Tomcat in Windows and Linux out of the box.
4. It works for JBoss EAP in Linux out of the box.

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-app-service-reference#resource-logs

We are in the process of documenting this.